# "Not Valid Expression" using SUM function with a single column (decimal, 11, 2)

Tags: sql, sum, db2, decimal, ibm-midrange

In excel, I am rewriting the commands within a query from AS400. One column that I am trying to rewrite is  decimal 11, 2.

Here is exactly what I wrote:

SUM (CA.B7A5QT) AS "Transaction Quantity"

Each time that I attempt to run this, it returns that it is an invalid expression.

Comment: Show the whole query

Comment: What product is used? Is this a QM query? Interactive SQL? Embedded SQL? What version of DB2 for i? Have you tried single-quotes in place of the doubles?

Comment: ...because double-quotes almost certainly aren't what you need in those locations, assuming it's "exactly" what you tried.

Comment: For SQL [no idea about Excel], the expression `SUM (CA.B7A5QT) AS "Transaction Quantity"` is valid\acceptable in a query [for reference to a column named B7A5QT, of a file either named or identified AS "CA"]; the double-quotes are required, as shown, in that context whereby the expression is assigned a name\identifier.  The OP really should define what "it" is in "it returns" and if "it" is the DB2 for i SQL, then what is the message identifier -- possibly SQL0122, implying the query likely is either missing a GROUP BY or the non-aggregate expressions are not also in the GROUP BY

Answer (score -1):

Since you didn't provide the whole query: is there a chance, that 'CA.B7A5QT' eventually becomes NULL?
If so try the following syntax:

```
SUM (IFNULL(CA.B7A5QT, 0)) AS "Transaction Quantity"
```